# Forcing floated elements to run off-screen

Tags: css

I have floated elements in a DIV which wrap onto the next line. Instead of wrapping, I would like these elements to simply run off the screen. I've tried using `white-space:nowrap` without success.

**CSS**

```
img {
    float: left;
}
div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <img ... >
        <img ... >
        <img ... >
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: where in the HTML is the text you want to overflow? overflow: hidden won't work for images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
img
{
    float: left;
}
div
{
    width: 300%;
}
body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that as well. The problem is, on touch-screens (like the iPhone) since the div runs off the screen, you can still scroll and see the overflowed content. That's actually fine with me, except that the width of the DIV isn't correct so there is usually extra white space. Any way to adapt this method so that the DIV shrinks to the contents while still running off-screen? (short of using a ton of JS to set the correct width)?